# Play song From Custom Listview On BuTTON CLICK with position

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have a list of longs which is `inflated` in `custom listview` with buttons. I want to play single song on single `button` click.
I get the position of button click and also passed the song in play song method. But it `eventually` its not playing any of the song. If I set  `playSong(1);` then the first song is playing. But if I set  `playSong(position);` then it will not play any song.

```
 public abstract class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable , SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> countryList;
ArrayList<String> mStringFilterList;
    LayoutInflater inflter;
    public ImageView img2;
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private SeekBar songProgressBar;

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, ArrayList<String> countryList) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.countryList = countryList;
        mStringFilterList =  countryList;

        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return countryList.size();
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<String> countryList) {
        this.countryList = countryList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.list_itemss, null);
        String hello = countryList.get(position);
        Log.d("Hello",hello);
            playSong(1);
        String henno1 = String.valueOf(hello.length());
        Log.d("hellya",henno1);
        songProgressBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);

        TextView country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        country.setText(hello);

        songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
        songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);


        img2 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast.makeText(Main.this,"Position is --"+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                int songIndex = position;

                playSong(songIndex);
                Log.d("song_index", String.valueOf(songIndex));

    /*I GET THE INDEX IN LOG*/

                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.pause();
                        // Changing button image to play button
                        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.playbutton);
                    }
                }else{
                    // Resume song
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.start();
                        // Changing button image to pause button
                        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.pausebutton);
                    }
                }

                Toast.makeText(Main.this,"Play Song",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        ImageView img =(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(Main.this,"Added to Playlist",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                file = new File(path.get(position));
               customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void  playSong(int songIndex){
        // Play song
        Toast.makeText(Main.this,"Song is Playing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        int m =songIndex;
//i ALSO GET THE POSITION IN LOG ON BUTTON CLICK BUT SONG IS NOT PLAYING.
        Log.d("Printsssss", String.valueOf(m));
        try {
            mp.start();
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            updateProgressBar();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to launch your player from the setOnItemClickListner of your activity.

When you launch your activity, the `getView()` method will be called for all items of your list view.

```
  listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              //You have to put here the code to get your song from list of songs
        }
  });
```

I can't help you more, i can't see declaration of variables "mp" and "songsList"

Answer (score 1):

`Adapter`'s responsibility is to populate your `List`, `RecyclerView` etc, `getView` is bound with single item. If your `Activity` or `Fragment` destroys you have to manually  release `MediaPlayer` resources, which will headche for you so simply you should play your songs by adding `onListItemClick` in your `Activity` or `Fragment`

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

}
```

Now you will have position to play and pause your respective song. Have fun :)